# Clear apache log or change log while apache is running

Tags: apache, file, logfile

I want to clear my Apache log without stopping apache or anything like that, but I have a problem while apache's running I can not edit the active log file.

I attempted some solutions but all is not good, or it just does not work - for example:

```
cat /dev/null > /path/to/log.log
```

It works but it kills the CPU.

Now I want to know has anybody got a good solution for clearing log files or creating a new log file with a new name every N hours which doesn't kill the CPU,RAM,etc ...

What can I do? Please give me a solution :((

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and set up logrotate, assuming you are on a debian or ubuntu distribution do this :

```
$ sudu apt-get install logrotate
```

This is an "industry standard" solution for what you want to achieve.

Recommended reading:

1. http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-ubuntu-part-1
2. http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-centos-part-1
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66292/learning-about-general-logging-logrotation-on-linux

Comment: in cent OS we need to install or don't need for install and in default that is available with apache ? do you know ? Kind regards

Comment: It's unlikely that logrotate would be installed with apache on centos (or any other distribution). To test if it is installed just type $which logrotate - if something is printed out, then it is installed :-) I've updated my answer to include a link to understanding logrotate on centos.